# How do I specify number of rows to drop in drop_duplicates in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with some accounting entries and accounting entries are double entries - which means two rows correspond to one transaction.

I am looking to do some analysis without double-counting these entries, at first I thought of using the drop_duplicates() method in pandas, but I found out it would drop identical entries that are booked more than once.

For example, 10 entries in the dataset represent 5 accounting entries, if these 5 accounting entries are identical the drop_duplicates() method would leave me only with 1 entry left.

Example input

```
A
A
A
A
B
B
```

Desired output

```
A
A
B
```

What is the quickest way to drop only half of the entries?

Comment: Hi There, welcome to SO please see [ask] and [mcve] from the sounds of it, your columns aren't _exactly_ identical, there must be some rhyme or reason for you wanting to keep half of the records, better if you post some data, expected output and your own research - i'll remove my downvote when you do.

Comment: rhyme or reason - These are accounting entries and they are double entries by nature, thats why I only want to keep half of it

Comment: I thought its a straightforward question which you already understand that "I want to keep half of the records"

Comment: Pardon my use of accounting jargon, double-entry means two entries correspond to 1 transaction, hence the reason I want to drop half of them. An input of 10x would yield a desired output of 5x. Nonetheless I have updated my question

Comment: single entry = `A`, dobule entry = `['A', 'A']` triple entry =  `['A','A','A']` whats the logic of keeping 2 of the three A's here?

Comment: In my case there would not be triple entries, I only want to turn ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A']  to ['A', 'A']

Comment: They are not duplicates, a same event happened 3 times does not mean I only need 1 data row that represent the 3 events. What I can do is I can do a count and a loop to reconstruct the table, but that's why I am asking for the "quickest" way to drop half of the duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to revisit your data and see where the `uniqueness` of each duplicate lay, you can add parameters to `drop_duplicates` such as `subset` and `keep` to specify your conditions.

That said, to handle this, we need to count each group and divide the count by a `size` of each group.

we can then keep those that meet the initial 50% threshold.

in one line.

```
print(df)

   0
0  A
1  A
2  A
3  A
4  B
5  B

df[((df.groupby(0).cumcount() + 1) / df.groupby(0)[0].transform('size')).le(0.5)]


   0
0  A
1  A
4  B
```